# how do we plot plotly surface plots with frequency values on Z axis python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, frequency

I have data as given below and I would want to plot interactive surface plot with frequency of values in x and y on z-axis

```
**apples**  **oranges**
    0           1
   10           2
   20           1
   10           1
   10           1
```

I tried below code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#
z_data = df.groupby(['apples', 'oranges']).count()

x, y = df['apples'], df['oranges']
sh_0, sh_1 = z.shape
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, x=x, y=y)])
#fig.update_layout(title='histogram_trial', autosize=True)

fig.update_layout(title='Mt Bruno Elevation', autosize=False,
                  width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
fig.show()
```

above code gives me blank output. Please let me know how do I get counts on z-axis

Comment: When you say frequency in values of x and y on the z-axis, can you explain what you mean? What would be the expected z-values for each x and y value?

Comment: Hi Derek, my z values should like as below  **apples** **oranges** ** z**
0 1 1
10 2 1
20 1 1
10 1 2

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of issues with your code.

1. [`DataFrameGroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) won't calculate anything because you
   don't have non-key columns to be subject to the aggregate. Use either
   [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) or [`DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html).
2. [`plotly.graph_objects.Surface`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Surface.html) has special input requirements:

   > The data the describes the coordinates of the surface is set in `z`. Data in `z` should be a 2D list. Coordinates in `x` and `y` can either be 1D lists or 2D lists (e.g. to graph parametric surfaces). If not provided in `x` and `y`, the x and y coordinates are assumed to be linear starting at 0 with a unit step.

Without fulfilling (2) you can only plot `Scatter3d` or `Mesh3d`. But with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) you can get the data in the right shape.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

raw_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(50, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])
df = raw_df.value_counts(['x', 'y']).reset_index(name='z')
surf_df = df.pivot_table(index=['y'], columns=['x'], values=['z'], fill_value=0)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=df['x'], y=df['y'], z=df['z'], mode='markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=surf_df))
fig
```

[image: surface plot]